# Use variables to call query in sync-mysql node js

Tags: mysql, node.js

```
var mysql= require('sync-mysql');
var connection = new mysql({
    host: 'host-name',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'tables', //name of the database
    multipleStatements: true
});

var val="value"
const ans= connection.queueQuery("Select * from table Where col_1=val";);
console.log(ans());
```

Despite a tuple existing for such a column, query is returning an empty array.
how do i use a local variable in a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use ES6 [*Template literals*:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
const ans = connection.queueQuery(`Select * from table Where col_1 = ${val}`);
```

Or simple concatenation:

```
const ans = connection.queueQuery('Select * from table Where col_1 = ' + val);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Although the first method didn't work.
What about inserting a value?

Comment: connection.queueQuery('INSERT INTO table VALUES ?' + [values]);
This is not Working. Can You help with this as well?

Comment: I think sync-mysql doesn't support value inserting in that way you comment.

Comment: So how do i perform insertion query using variables?

Comment: "insert into table (col1, col2 colN)  values ("  + variable1 + "," + variable2 + "," + variableN  + ")"